# Calling processing-java from nodejs on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, processing

I am having some problems to execute the processing-java on windows from nodejs. When I use the following

```
processing-java --sketch=$pwd/sketch/ --run
```

in the console it works fine and the sketch is executed, window opens and the result is a file written to a directory where I need it.

But when I use the same as a string in the node file to execute it, it does not open a window and no file has been written, but the callback function processOutput is executed, hence the somehow the execution happened.

I added

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
```

to the js file which is used for executing child processes in node.
$pwd is the PowerShell equivalent to pwd on MacOS.
exec should execute the shell command and call the callback function. The callback function is executed, but not the sketch.

```
const cmd = 'processing-java --sketch=$pwd/sketch/ --run';
exec(cmd, processOutput);
```

What am I missing? Any help appreceated.
Many thanks, C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`child_process.exec()` does not execute in a powershell but in a CMD terminal. Thus you can't use powershell variables like `$pwd`. You could try using `%CD%` instead

```
const cmd = 'processing-java --sketch=%CD%/sketch/ --run';
exec(cmd, processOutput);
```